# How check in mypy that variable has "Literal[...]?" type?

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

I make plugin for mypy. We have [context-sensitive literals](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/literal_types.html#declaring-literal-variables) denoted by a question mark at the end: `Literal[..]?`. It has a field called `last_known_value` with type `Literal` and the same content.
How can I check whether a variable has a CS-literal type? I've found instructions for checking simple `Literal` types, but they don't work for CS-Literal types.
Sure, I can just try to get the field last_known_value and throw an exception, but I hope there is a better solution.

Below is some pseudocode attempting to determine the type.

```
a : Literal[..]
b : Literal[..]?

ininstance(a, Literal) -> ok
isinstance(b, Literal) -> exception: typing.Literal cannot be used with isinstance()

type(a) -> mypy.types.LiteralType
type(b) -> mypy.types.Instance (???)
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what `mypy.types.LiteralType` and `mypy.types.Instance` mean, and what mypy does in general. They're *not* part of the typing system, and not part of your standard Python runtime; they're part of mypy's internal representation of an abstract syntax tree built by parsing a piece of Python code. There is never a Python runtime where `isinstance(a, typing.Literal) -> ok`.